# How can we get environment variable into Java from AWS CodeBuild?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-ssm, aws-credentials

Check the below image as I already set the Environment Variable with ACCESS and SECRET Key into CodeBuild AWS.
[image]
And I am trying to get those data into JAVA Project with the below code but unable to get value and get null output.

```
    String access_key = System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
    String secret_key = System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");
    
    System.err.println("access_key " + access_key);
    System.err.println("secret_key " + secret_key);
```

Also tried with the below way but was unable to get the value of it.

```
System.err.println("Access key: "+StringParameter.valueFromLookup(this,"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
```

Also did the below way but did not get any success.

```
System.err.println("Access : "+EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create().resolveCredentials().accessKeyId());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It goes beyond the question, but you NEVER share your AWS ACCESS KEY and SECRET KEY, moreover you never store them anywhere as plaintext, besides you local machine. If you need AWS access, you rely on giving the necessary roles and permissions to the services which runs your code. Afterwards, in your code you use the default credentials provider chain: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html which will be able to fetch the necessary authentication tokens.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi It's working fine in my local system but it is not working in the AWS machine so need access and a secret key from the environment variable and use it for further tasks.

Comment: Is this Java code being invoked by CodeBuild, or is it being built by CodeBuild and invoked elsewhere?

Comment: @Parsifal Code execution is invoked in code build not else where.

Comment: Can you show the CodeBuild script that you're running? As text, not a picture.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. Instead, you should grant the necessary rights to the codebuild action's role.